# Create comma-separated string from array column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, delimited

Do we have any array function in PHP to get this:

```
// get all the user ids as comma seprated.
$users = array();
foreach($view as $result)
{       
    $users[] = $result->uid;            
}
$uid = implode(',', $users);
```

Example:

```
$array[0] = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
$array[1] = array("size" => "XLL", "color" => "siver");
$array[2] = array("size" => "M", "color" => "purple");
```

I need

```
$color = "gold,silver,purple";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode(',', $view) in order to get the values array.

Answer (score 0):

From your updated question:

You could try something like this:

'firstname_value','lastname'=>'lastname_value'); 

sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ("%s")', 'table_name', implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($values))), implode('", "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $values))); 

//that gives you: INSERT INTO table_name (firstname, lastname) VALUES ("firstname_value", "lastname_value") 

?>

Comment: Sorry this method will not help me.